# Salesforce1 Mobile Browser

Tags: mobile, salesforce1-platform

We use Salesforce1 browser app using a secured browser(not Salesforce1 downloadable app from google play/apple store). I want to know how many users logged in today using SF1 - report/query. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LoginHistory](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginhistory.htm) Object for Query and get all user logged in related information. Including the Browser name, Ip adrress, User Id etc.

There might be some cases like you login from computer and after that from your mobile in SF1. Now in login history it will display last login from SF1 whether you are querying from desktop as current browser. To handle this use IP address and filter record based on IP address and Id.

Comment: Hi Tushar, I thought getting browser in a report would fetch me desired results, but when I log in using a chrome browser/IE on desktop - it is reported as safari/mobilechrome. That part is confusing to me

Comment: Hi @Laxmi strange it is working for me. Can you check LoginHistory under manage user in setup and check you are getting correct browser name there?

Comment: Hey Tushar, I have tried going that route - but it gives me wrong browser information. Have you tried eventlogfile?